# some parts of my form is rendering correctly but some arent Django

Tags: python, django

I am creating a ticket app in my django project. When I create a ticket and submit, parts of the form render correctly in the frontend except three fields. These are the `ticket.name`, `category.name` and `ticket.description`, in the frontend these fields display as 'None' but everything else renders as its supposed to in the frontend. I also checked my admin page and i see that neither the `Ticket` nor the `Category` get created properly. I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Here's what i have so far

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or ''
    
class Ticket(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (True, 'Open'),
        (False, 'Closed')
    )
    
    PRIORITIES = (
        ('None', 'None'),
        ('Low', 'Low'),
        ('Medium', 'Medium'),
        ('High', 'High')
    )
    
    TYPE = (
        ('Misc', 'Misc'),
        ('Bug', 'Bug'),
        ('Help Needed', 'Help Needed'),
        ('Concern', 'Concern'),
        ('Question', 'Question')
    )
    
    host = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='host')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='category')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(choices=STATUS, default=True)
    priority = models.TextField(choices=PRIORITIES, default='None', max_length=10)
    type = models.TextField(choices=TYPE, default='Misc', max_length=15)
    description = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)
    # description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, related_name='participants', blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name or ''
```

views.py

view for creating a ticket

```
def createTicket(request):
    form = TicketForm()
    
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category_name = request.POST.get('category')
        category, created = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=category_name)
        
        ticket = Ticket.objects.create(
            host = request.user,
            category=category,
            name=request.POST.get('name'),
            status=request.POST.get('status'),
            priority=request.POST.get('priority'),
            type=request.POST.get('type'),
            description=request.POST.get('description'),
        )
        
        return redirect('ticket', pk=ticket.id)
    
    context = {'form': form, 'categories': categories}
    return render(request, 'projects/ticket_form.html', context)
```

view for ticket page

```
def ticket(request, pk):
    ticket = Ticket.objects.get(id=pk)
    ticket_messages = ticket.message_set.all()
    participants = ticket.participants.all()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = Message.objects.create(
            user=request.user,
            ticket=ticket,
            body=request.POST.get('body')
        )
        ticket.participants.add(request.user)
        return redirect('ticket', pk=ticket.id)
    
    context = {'ticket': ticket, 'ticket_messages': ticket_messages, 
               'participants': participants}
    return render(request, 'projects/ticket.html', context)
```

here is part of the template for the ticket page

```
<div class="column-layout">
                    <div class="main-column">
                        <h1>{{ticket.name}}</h1>
                        {{ticket.description|safe }}
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <div class="sidebar-two">
                        <span style="white-space: pre-line"><label for="room_topic">Enter a Category</label>
                            <input required type="text" value="{{ticket.category.name}}" name="topic" list="topic-list" />
                            <datalist id="topic-list">
                            <select id="room_topic">
                              {% for category in categories %}
                              <option value="{{category.name}}">{{category.name}}</option>
                              {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                            </datalist>
                            </span>
                          <div class="form__group">
                            <span style="white-space: pre-line"><label for="room_name">Assigned to</label>
                              {{ticket.assigned}}</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form__group">
                            <span style="white-space: pre-line"><label for="room_name">Ticket Status</label>
                              {{ticket.status|yesno:'Open,Closed'}}</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form__group">
                            <span style="white-space: pre-line"><label for="room_name">Ticket Priorities</label>
                              {{ticket.priority}}</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form__group">
                            <span style="white-space: pre-line"><label for="room_name">Ticket Type</label>
                              {{ticket.type}}</span>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is what it looks like in the admin page. The `Ticket` database looks the same

[image]

Comment: It looks like you don't set name correctly, because it's empty. Do you really need `null=True` there? Another thing - `category.name` is not valid, you need to use relation: `ticket.category.name`.

Comment: You shouldn't use get_or_create if your field isn't set to unique as that can raise multiple objects returned error if more then 1 category has same name, and follow the instructions provided by @NixonSparrow in the comment above (Remove that null=True, that might be the main issue)